# While loop in TSQL didn´t work in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i tried to execute an Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Script over odbc with the ibatis Script Runner(http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/dev/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.html)

```
 Connection "con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Database")" 

ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con, true, false);
// Give the input file to Reader
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aSQLScriptFilePath));
// Execute script
sr.runScript(reader);
```

"aSQLScriptFilePath" is a long and complex sqlscript. Where every statement is seperated with ";". Most of the Script works, bu there is the problem, that while loops inside the script  didnt get executed correctly. In the example below should be created an table with 1000rows but it only generates 386 rows inside the while loop.Everything else will be executed correctly(except the while loops). Also i didnt get a error in Java. I dont understand why the while loop wasnt executed correctly. If i try the Script directly in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 everything works fine . I have tried the native java method statement.execute(SQLScriptconvertedInOne String) and executeBatch() both have the same problem, that they abort the execution in the while loop.

Thank you in advance!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE test(
spalte1 int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

DECLARE @variable int = 1
WHILE (@variable<=1000)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test
SELECT @variable
SET @variable=@variable+1
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method that does not use WHILE LOOP

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE test(
spalte1 int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test
SELECT top 1000 row_number() over (order by (select 0)) FROM sys.columns as sys1 
cross join sys.columns as sys2
```

Comment: works better, but it also generates only 715 rows and not 1000,
and it throws the error:" Error executing: INSERT INTO looptest
SELECT top 1000 row_number() over (order by (select 0)) FROM sys.columns
.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Hurt the PRIMARY KEY-restriktion'PK__looptest__621ECEB16718A719'. The Keyvalue (1) is used double.

Comment: Nothing. You first executed it where it added only 715 rows. When you execute it, again numbers from 1 to 1000 got inserted and caused the PRIMARY KEY violation error